# Jacoco Maven offline instrumentation - Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, integration-testing, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I am trying to get code coverage report for integration tests. Jacoco maven plugin is able to give the code coverage for unit tests , but giving 0% coverage for the integration tests. The integration tests are hitting the rest api end points of the app, which has been deployed in tomcat.

My maven jacoco plugin & surefire plugin look like this.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.9</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>prepare-agent</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>prepare-agent-integration</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent-integration</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>report</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>post-unit-test</id>
                    <phase>integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/target/jacoco-it.exec</dataFile>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/target/jacoco-ut</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>

            <configuration>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <jacoco-agent.destfile>target/jacoco.exec</jacoco-agent.destfile>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.20</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- <skip>true</skip> -->
                <!-- <systemPropertyVariables> <jacoco-agent.destfile>target/jacoco.exec</jacoco-agent.destfile> 
                    </systemPropertyVariables> -->
            </configuration>
            <!-- <configuration> <skip>true</skip> </configuration> -->
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unit-tests</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- Never skip running the tests when the test phase is invoked -->
                        <!-- <skip>true</skip> -->
                        <argLine>@{argLine}
                            -javaagent:c:\\iat\\mavenrepository\\org\\jacoco\\org.jacoco.agent\\0.7.10-SNAPSHOT\\org.jacoco.agent-0.7.10-SNAPSHOT-runtime.jar=destfile=C:\\Users\\dmahapat\\Workspaces\\MyEclipse
                            2016 CI\\JaxRsApp\\target\\jacoco.exec</argLine>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*UnitTest.java</include>
                        </includes>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/*IntegrationTest.java</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>integration-tests</id>
                    <phase>integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- Never skip running the tests when the integration-test phase 
                            is invoked -->
                        <!-- argLine>-javaagent:$WORKSPACE/target/lib/jacoco-agent-0.7.9.jar=includes=*,destfile=*/jacoco-coverage.exec,append=false</argLine -->
                        <skip>false</skip>
                        <argLine>@{argLine}
                            -javaagent:c:\\iat\\mavenrepository\\org\\jacoco\\org.jacoco.agent\\0.7.10-SNAPSHOT\\org.jacoco.agent-0.7.10-SNAPSHOT-runtime.jar=destfile=C:\\Users\\dmahapat\\Workspaces\\MyEclipse
                            2016 CI\\JaxRsApp\\target\\jacoco-it.exec
                        </argLine>

                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*IntegrationTest.java</include>
                        </includes>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/*UnitTest.java</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I am executing unit tests in test phase & integration tests in integration test phase.
The latest error that i get is "Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing execution data file."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Evgeny's help, i made this work.
Changed server to glassfish & ide to intellij for easier debugging.

Start glassfish server with following JVM options.

```
-DargLine=-javaagent:c:/iat/mavenrepository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.9/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.9-runtime.jar=destfile=C:/dmahapat_JaxRsApp/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec
```

Updated pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.mathworks</groupId>
<artifactId>JaxRsApp</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>JaxRsApp</name>

<build>
    <finalName>JaxRsApp</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-test-source</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-test-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>${project.basedir}\src\integration-test\java</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-test-resource</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-test-resource</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <!-- Don't forget <directory> label -->
                                <directory>${project.basedir}\src\integration-test\resources</directory>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.9</version>
            <executions>
                <!--
                    Prepares the property pointing to the JaCoCo runtime agent which
                    is passed as VM argument when Maven the Surefire plugin is executed.
                -->
                <execution>
                    <id>pre-unit-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
                        <destFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</destFile>
                        <!--
                            Sets the name of the property containing the settings
                            for JaCoCo runtime agent.
                        -->
                        <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <!--
                    Ensures that the code coverage report for unit tests is created after
                    unit tests have been run.
                -->
                <execution>
                    <id>post-unit-test</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
                        <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</dataFile>
                        <!-- Sets the output directory for the code coverage report. -->
                        <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-ut</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

                <execution>
                    <id>pre-integration-test</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
                        <destFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec</destFile>
                        <!--
                            Sets the name of the property containing the settings
                            for JaCoCo runtime agent.
                        -->
                        <propertyName>failsafeArgLine</propertyName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <!--
                    Ensures that the code coverage report for integration tests after
                    integration tests have been run.
                -->
                <execution>
                    <id>post-integration-test</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
                        <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec</dataFile>
                        <!-- Sets the output directory for the code coverage report. -->
                        <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-it</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>

        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.1</version>
            <configuration>
               <argLine>${surefireArgLine}</argLine>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*IntegrationTest*</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.1</version>
            <configuration>
              <argLine>${failsafeArgLine}</argLine>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*IntegrationTest.java</include>
                </includes>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*UnitTest.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>integration-tests</id>
                    <phase>integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
        <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpmime -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.7</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<properties>
    <jersey.version>2.25.1</jersey.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

</properties>
```

Answer (score 1):

Quoting [documentation of `prepare-agent-integration`](http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/prepare-agent-integration-mojo.html):

> Same as prepare-agent, but provides default values suitable for integration-tests:
>
> - bound to pre-integration-test phase
> - different destFile

Quoting [documentation of `prepare-agent`](http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/prepare-agent-mojo.html):

> Prepares a property pointing to the JaCoCo runtime agent that can be **passed as a VM argument to the application under test**. Depending on the project packaging type by default a property with the following name is set:
>
> - tycho.testArgLine for packaging type eclipse-test-plugin and
> - argLine otherwise.

In most cases `argLine` is automatically picked by `maven-surefire-plugin` that starts JVM to execute unit tests - http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#argLine

> argLine: Arbitrary JVM options to set on the command line.

This explains why you're getting coverage for unit tests.

To get the coverage for integration tests you must make sure that this property is passed to JVM of application under test, i.e. JVM that executes Tomcat, what is entirely and solely depends on a way you're launching it.

Comment: Do i need to start tomcat by providing  following argument   -javaagent:c:\\iat\\mavenrepository\\org\\jacoco\\org.jacoco.agent\\0.7.10-SNAPSHOT\\org.jacoco.agent-0.7.10-SNAPSHOT-runtime.jar=destfile=C:\\Users\\dmahapat\\Workspaces\\MyEclipse2016 CI\\JaxRsApp\\target\\jacoco-it.exec

Comment: If you're using Maven to start Tomcat, then `jacoco-maven-plugin` prepares this argument for you, so you just need to pass it to Tomcat as a usual Maven property - `${argLine}`.

Comment: @debajyotimahapatro please don't forget to upvote helpful and accept+upvote correct answers to be a good user of this site.

Comment: Hi Govin, we switched to glassfish 4.1.0 & added arg line as a jvm-options in domain.xml infollowing format <jvm-options>-DargLine=-javaagent:c:/iat/mavenrepository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.9/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.9-runtime.jar=destfile=C:/Users/dmahapat/Workspaces/MyEclipse 2016 CI/dmahapat_JaxRsApp 2/target/jacoco-it.exec</jvm-options>
But each time we try to restart glassfish , the jvm options get erased & we still see the same error "Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing execution data file." Can i share the latest pom with you some how?

Comment: Looks like , i was getting this error as we had spaces in the path. I changed it to <jvm-options>-DargLine=-javaagent:c:/iat/mavenrepository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.9/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.9-runtime.jar=destfile=C:\Users\dmahapat\Workspaces\MyEcli~1\dmahap~1\target\jacoco-it.exec</jvm-options> & restarted glassfish. Now i still get 0% coverage in the report.  "Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing execution data file." error is still there